# Sandwich theorem for derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

"Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an interval which contains $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $M$ and $m$ two functions defined on $I$, differentiable at $a$ and $f$ a function defined on $I$ which takes value in $\mathbb{R}$.

If :

1. $\forall x\in I$, $m(x) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M(x)$,
2. $m(a)=f(a)=M(a)$.

Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and we have $f′(a) = m′(a) = M′(a)$.

I have a simple proof for this theorem I want to check that:

Let $q(x)=f(x)-m(x)$.  $q(x)$ is always non-negative in $I$, so $a$ is the extremum point for $q$ so $q'(a)=0$ so $f'(a)=m'(a)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: That $q$ has a minimum at $a$ does not imply that $q'(a)$ exists. Consider $q(x) = \lvert x\rvert$. You need to use the given properties to deduce that $q$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: You did not use the property $f(x)\leq M(x)$ in your proof - actually, $M$ did not show up at all which clearly implies that your proof misses something. So use all the Information given to prove the statement!

Comment: yes you are right and i know something is wrong but I don't know what is it

Comment: f is differentiable at a and m is also differentiable at a so q is differentiable at a too

Comment: That $f$ is differentiable at $a$ is part of what you want to _conclude_, it's not a given hypothesis. What you are given is that $M$ is differentiable at $a$, like $m$ is. So for $p(x) = M(x) - m(x)$ we have $p(x) \geqslant 0$, $p(a) = 0$, and differentiability of $p$ at $a$, so $p'(a) = 0$. Then you can use $0 \leqslant q(x) \leqslant p(x)$ to deduce the differentiability of $q$ at $a$.